# $f$ entire function with $|f(z)| \leq 1 + |\Im z|$, is $f$ constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be entire such that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, $|f(z)| \leq 1 + |\Im(z)|$. Is $f$ constant?

I think it is linear and non-constant: For $a_{n}$ the $n$-th coefficient in the power series of $f$ about the origin [and $C_{R} := \partial D(0, R)$], we have

$$|a_{n}| \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{C_{R}} \frac{1 + |\Im(z)|}{|z|^{n+1}} dz \leq \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} R \cdot \frac{1 + R|\sin t|}{R^{n+1}} dt = \frac{1}{R^{n}} + \frac{2}{\pi R^{n-1}}.$$

Letting $R \rightarrow \infty$, $|a_{n}|$ will be $0$ when $n > 1$. Since I've only bounded above, I can't say anything about $a_{1}$. On the other hand, I can't find an example of a non-constant $f$ satisfying the hypothesis.

Comment: If you're saying $f(z)=az$ is valid ($a\neq 0$), then you can clearly obtain a contradiction by looking at $z=x+0i$, and take $x$ to be arbitrarily big.

Comment: @AlexR. Ah duh... okay thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
|f(z)| \leq 1 + |\Im(z)| \le 1 + |z|
$$
implies that $f$ is (at most) linear, i.e.
$$
f(z) = a_0 + a_1 z
$$
with complex constants $a_0, a_1$. Now choose $z = x \in\Bbb R$ with $x\to \infty$ to conclude that $a_1=0$ and $f$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

One general tool that applies to such situations is the [Phragmen–Lindelöf theorem](http://math.iisc.ac.in/~manju/TA/6-phragmenlindelof.pdf), which extends the maximum modulus principle to unbounded domains as long as the function in question doesn't grow too fast. In this case, we have $|f(z)| \le 1$ on the boundary of the upper half plane (namely the real axis), and the growth bound is easily enough to apply Phragmen–Lindelöf, whereby $|f(z)| \le 1$ on the entire upper half plane. The same applies to the lower half plane, and so $|f(z)|\le1$ everywhere, hence is constant.